# Chrome history and favorites in Spotlight?

Tags: google-chrome, spotlight

I have fallen in love with the new Spotlight window in Yosemite as a replacement for Quicksilver (or Alfred, or whatever).

However I would love to be able to "search" into Chrome favorites and history. A bit like if I searched into Chrome's address bar.

Is there any way to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, thus far the only browser tied into Spotlight like that is Safari, which is one its major selling points (and the main reason I won't use FF, or now Chrome, as my primary browser.)

The beauty of the Safari/Spotlight connection goes beyond bookmarks, however. Spotlight actually creates an index of all the text on each page you visit. I set my Safari to never delete and now I find myself creating far less bookmarks. If, for instance, two years from now I remember reading a page about best places to stay in Tulum, I can just search my Safari index from Spotlight and pull up that page. I don't need to have ever bookmarked it and I don't need to start over with the web.

It's a little known, but very clever, innovation that Apple provides with Safari and Spotlight.